# Is there a workaround for argmin/argmax aggregation in Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am looking into a way of computing argmin or argmax aggregation of multiple rows in Snowflake similar to Hive or Presto.

In Hive, one can use a workaround with (named) structs because the aggregation function gets applied to the first element of the struct. Here is an example:

```sql
SELECT max(named_struct('y', y, 'x', x)).x FROM t
```

Now I am asking myself if there is a similar way to do this in Snowflake.

In Snowflake we have an `OBJECT` datatype with similar properties. Can I use the following code to compute argmin or argmax like in the Hive example? Are min/max aggregations for objects also performed on the first element of the object?

```sql
SELECT max(object_construct('y', y, 'x', x)).x FROM t
```

Running the above code returns an error: `SQL compilation error: Function MAX does not support OBJECT argument type.`. It actually doesn't support any complex type.

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood the logic of argmin(), then you could implement it as a javascript UDF like so:

```
create or replace function argmin("a" object, "b" object)
  returns object
  language javascript
as
$$

    for (let [k,v] of Object.entries(a))
        if (v==b[k])
            continue
        else 
            return v < b[k] ? a : b

    return b

$$;
```

And applied like this:

```
with t as (
  select 
     object_construct('x',1, 'y',2) a, 
     object_construct('x',2, 'y',1) b
)
select argmin(t.a,t.b):y from t;
```

---

Actually this functionality is built in:

```
select 
    object_construct('x',1, 'y',2) a, 
    object_construct('x',2, 'y',1) b, 
    iff(a<b, a, b) : y
;
```

---

Even more concisely:

```
select 
   object_construct('x',1, 'y',2) a, 
   object_construct('x',2, 'y',1) b,
   least(a,b):y,
   greatest(a,b):y;
```

Comment: Nice, nice. is this documented somewhere how a<b works for objects?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing it but I don't see any documentation on object equality.

Comment: I am actually looking for an argmax aggregation function rather than argmax of 2 values